# How to avoid circular association (Class Diagram)

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have a Project class that has one Objective. an Objective that has many Projects. a Meeting that can be associated to a Project (which has an Objective) or Objective. How can I represent this relationship in a Class Diagram

I know it shouldn't be done this way
[image: I know it shouldn't be done this way]

Comment: Well, all the `id` attributes are for the bin and all your classes are abstract. So this way it's no business domain model at all.

Comment: What is your concern with "circular association"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem in UML with circular associations.  This is common business as soon as you model real life domains. You could even have self-associating classes in a circular association, and it still wouldn't be an issue.

Your only modelling challenge is to represent accurately:

> A `Meeting` that can be associated to a `Project` (which has an `Objective`) or `Objective`.

You must therefore first disambiguate:

- can it be none of the two (your diagram gets it) ?
- can it be both?  If yes:

  - can the meeting's objective be different from the project objective (your diagram still gets it) ?
  - or shall objectives of the meeting and the project be aligned (see my [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75514668/3723423),  how to express constraints between direct and indirect associated classes using OCL)
- must it be the one or the other but not both (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76431771/3723423) for the best recent answers on this topic)?